# JSON Formatting from Particle Photon Webhook to Azure

Tags: javascript, json, azure, storage

I have hooked up my Particle Photon to log my temperature and then publishing the events to eventhub at Microsoft Azure. Then i use Stream Analytics to output the JSON file into Azure Storage (Good idea? or not?).

When i try to open it with `<script src="URL"></script>` through HTML, i get **" Uncaught Syntax error: Unexpected token : "** in the browser console window.
I also tried to validate my JSON file with JSON formatter and got alot of errors.

Here is the JSON file: https://pptlbhstorage.blob.core.windows.net/temperature/0_d1e8a2b709b14461b5ac12265f33020b_1.json

From the stream analytics i created a job with this query:

```
CREATE TABLE pptlbhhub (
  coreid nvarchar(max),
  data nvarchar(max),
  event nvarchar(max),
  EventEnqueuedUtcTime datetime,
  EventProcessedUtcTime datetime,  
  measurename nvarchar(max),
  PartitionId bigint,
  published_at datetime,
  subject nvarchar(max),
  timecreated datetime,
  unitofmeasure nvarchar(max),
  value float
);

SELECT
   coreid
  ,event
  ,EventEnqueuedUtcTime
  ,EventProcessedUtcTime
  ,measurename
  ,PartitionId
  ,published_at
  ,subject
  ,timecreated
  ,unitofmeasure
  ,value
INTO
    pptlbhstorage
FROM
    pptlbhhub;
```

Comment: Your JSON output is invalid. Fix the format until it passes validation and it will work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I mean your file should look like this to be JSON valid (like an array). 
**[**{"coreid":"1e0041000c47343432313031","displayname":"IoT Assignment 3","event":"PublishToEventHub","eventenqueuedutctime":"2016-05-12T08:56:20.5300000Z","eventprocessedutctime":"2016-05-12T08:56:21.3068971Z","guid":"1e0041000c47343432313031","location":"Oslo","measurename":"Temperature","organization":"Westerdals ACT","partitionid":0,"published_at":"2016-05-12T08:56:21.0850000Z","subject":"Weather","timecreated":"2016-05-12T08:56:21.0850000Z","unitofmeasure":"F","value":21.0}**,**
{"coreid":"1e0041000c47343432313031","displayname":"IoT Assignment 3","event":"PublishToEventHub","eventenqueuedutctime":"2016-05-12T08:56:20.5300000Z","eventprocessedutctime":"2016-05-12T08:56:21.3068971Z","guid":"1e0041000c47343432313031","location":"Oslo","measurename":"Temperature","organization":"Westerdals ACT","partitionid":0,"published_at":"2016-05-12T08:56:21.0850000Z","subject":"Weather","timecreated":"2016-05-12T08:56:21.0850000Z","unitofmeasure":"F","value":21.0}**,** ...**]**

Not like
{"coreid":"1e0041000c47343432313031","displayname":"IoT Assignment 3","event":"PublishToEventHub","eventenqueuedutctime":"2016-05-12T08:56:20.5300000Z","eventprocessedutctime":"2016-05-12T08:56:21.3068971Z","guid":"1e0041000c47343432313031","location":"Oslo","measurename":"Temperature","organization":"Westerdals ACT","partitionid":0,"published_at":"2016-05-12T08:56:21.0850000Z","subject":"Weather","timecreated":"2016-05-12T08:56:21.0850000Z","unitofmeasure":"F","value":21.0}
{"coreid":"1e0041000c47343432313031","displayname":"IoT Assignment 3","event":"PublishToEventHub","eventenqueuedutctime":"2016-05-12T08:56:20.5300000Z","eventprocessedutctime":"2016-05-12T08:56:21.3068971Z","guid":"1e0041000c47343432313031","location":"Oslo","measurename":"Temperature","organization":"Westerdals ACT","partitionid":0,"published_at":"2016-05-12T08:56:21.0850000Z","subject":"Weather","timecreated":"2016-05-12T08:56:21.0850000Z","unitofmeasure":"F","value":21.0}...

**The difference is the "[]" at the beginning & the end of the stream and the "," between each element.**

Comment: I see it now! i will try to restructure my webhook. I'll tell you if it works or not

Comment: This should validate your JSON which is your first issue here, please don't forget to mark as solved ;)

Comment: I think the problem is in my stream analytics and not the code itself. I think i am using Azure wrong. because for every event, my device publishes this JSON object to the event hub : https://gyazo.com/b5032c2e7e34ca47fedfc5499d64594a what i wanna do is to put everything in a list. Could the solution be a hack with a file reader where i add ", " to each object?

Comment: I am thinking, would it better to instead use stream analytics to output it to a database, and then use an webAPI to parse the data to JSON ?

Comment: No blob is fine. Looks like you can choose to serialize either separate objects or array: the format should be specified as mentioned here: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/dn835015.aspx => format : associated with the serialization element and is optional when the serialization type is JSON. It is a string and supports the following values:
 - lineSeparated (Specifies that the output will be formatted by having each JSON object separated by a new line)
- array (Specifies that the output will be formatted as an array of JSON objects)
 Default value is lineSeparated.

Comment: I dont quite understand... do i have to do this with code? or through the azure portal? I created blob from the stream with the query  (updated my post)

Comment: Yes in the output config of the stream analytics job on the azure portal, you can specify the format as an "array" instead of "line separated" which is the default. It's the last parameter in the output config page.

Comment: So basically then my JSON object will be listed as array per event?

Comment: It should now be an array of events instead of distincts events that are line-separated (which is what you had in your file). This will fix your issue. Please, could you mark as solved ?

Comment: It is solved but the new json file looks like this: 
https://pptlbhstorage.blob.core.windows.net/temperature/0_7622a22009224c78a46c0b2bc0a3fd82_1.json

If you look at the end it doesn't include ]

Comment: This is a normal behaviour : the events are appended all along to the file as time goes to the JSON array, so your feed is not finished with ']' as events go on coming, so you may add the final "]" to your file extract when you need to use it as a validated JSON stream.

Comment: So i should do something like: Create a controller in ASP.net MVC (to show temperature data on the browser) that reads this JSON file and adds "]" to the final? 

or should i do something like this on startup.cs or something cause i want to have "up-to-date" data. Or doesnt it matter if u use GetBlobReference ?

Comment: Just add the ']' after getting the stream from the blob or before you want to use it as JSON (it can be on your page or anywhere else). There are many ways to achieve that depending on your needs and how you structure your code..

Answer (score 1):

If you output the events as an array, your JSON file will be ok :
[{}, {}, ...] 
instead of
{} {} {} ...

Comment: so my webhook looks like this now: https://gyazo.com/e34e7bac6893b950a7f166c78e384398
But should rather look like this?
https://gyazo.com/455795ddabc1fdae20db64ada777867c

Answer (score 1):

You might be interested Particle's 1st class integration with Azure IoT Hub to help you get Particle device data into Microsoft Azure. For more information on how to get this set up, check out:

https://docs.particle.io/tutorials/integrations/azure-iot-hub/